# Is there a way to optimize grouping of joined RDDs in Scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have just started learning Scala and Spark and this is the method where I've tried to join sale items and cars. `Sale items` represent information about car sales (carId, saleDate, cityofSale, price). `Cars` is a just a tuple with cars info (carId, carName). `ReportItem` is a final report (carId, carName, saleDate, cityofSale, price).

The method returns the expected result: `ReportItems` which have the maximum prices for a given carId/saleDate.
As a beginner in Scala/Spark I could have missed something so I want to ask for an advice. Is there a way to implement the method more optimally from the point of Scala opportunities. I had an idea to use a reduceByKey() method. But could not find a way to implement it properly in the method. I'll be grateful for any suggestions and critique.

```
    def getSales(sales: RDD[SaleItem], cars: RDD[(String, String)]): RDD[ReportItem] = {
        val mappedSales = sales.keyBy(_.carId)
        val mappedCars = cars.keyBy(_._1)
        mappedSales.join(mappedCars)
          .map({
            case (_, (saleItem, car)) => ReportItem(saleItem.carId, car._2, saleItem.saleDate, saleItem.city, saleItem.price)
          })
          .map(reportItem => ((reportItem.carId, reportItem.saleDate), reportItem))
          .groupByKey()
          .map({ case ((id, date), reportItem) => reportItem.maxBy(_.price) })
}
```

Comment: using carId or carName will help in readability than using _1 or _2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, its possible to optimize it using `.reduceByKey()`

```
def getSales(sales: RDD[SaleItem], cars: RDD[(String, String)]): RDD[ReportItem] = {
        val mappedSales = sales.keyBy(_.carId)
        val mappedCars = cars.keyBy(_._1)
        mappedSales.join(mappedCars)
          .map({
            case (_, (saleItem, car)) => ReportItem(saleItem.carId, car._2, saleItem.saleDate, saleItem.city, saleItem.price)
          })
          .map(reportItem => ((reportItem.carId, reportItem.saleDate), reportItem))
          .reduceByKey((item1, item2) => if(item1.price > item2.price) item1 else item2) //item1 & item2 are of type: ReportItem
          .values
}
```

This is more efficient because, We are holding only one `ReportItem` for a given `(carId, saleDate)` pair, as the `ReportItem` with max price is resolved then and there. The `groupBy` in your code holds `Iterable` of all `ReportItem` for a given pair in memory and calculates max at the end, which is a serious memory hog especially if the data is skewed.